# Why does COUNT(*) return a different number than SELECT for same filter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[PLEASE IGNORE...problem solved! should not have been asked...]
I am trying to get a count of my new users in the past 24 hours; and I want to verify that count by listing the users -- but I am getting two different results for what should be the same query.

After searching for an answer, and finding none, I am at a loss to explain why these two different SQL queries are returning different numbers, when they should be equivalent.

They are both Ruby scripts that connects to the same Postgres database.

The first query is a count:

```
cu = con.exec "SELECT count(*) AS user_count
    FROM Users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Personal_profiles p ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.updated_at >= TIMESTAMP 'YESTERDAY 23:00:00' - INTERVAL '1 day'
    AND u.updated_at < TIMESTAMP 'YESTERDAY 23:00:00'
    AND u.approved_for_transfer"

    user_count = cu.getvalue(0,0)
    puts "Count of Users created in past 24 hrs:", user_count
```

Which returns a count of 138.

The next query is a listing of similar records:

```
ru = con.exec "SELECT u.id,u.email, u.created_at::DATE, p.first_name,p.last_name 
    FROM Users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Personal_profiles p ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.created_at >= TIMESTAMP 'YESTERDAY 23:00:00' - INTERVAL '1 day'
    AND u.created_at < TIMESTAMP 'YESTERDAY 23:00:00'
    AND u.approved_for_transfer
    ORDER BY u.created_at DESC"

    puts "Users created in last 24 hr period (reverse chronological order):"

    puts "user.id  email   created_at   first_name    last_name"
    puts "-------  -----   ----------   ----------    ----------"
    ru.each do |row|
    puts "%s %s %s %s %s" % [ row['id'], row['email'], row['created_at'], row['first_name'], row['last_name'] ]
```

But this query return 53 lines, which is 51 records (since the first two lines are headers).

I believe I have the same join and filters in both cases, but if someone can explain why the queries return different results, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first query filters on `updated_at` an the other on `created_at`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto make that an answer

Answer (score 6):

The first query filters on `updated_at` and the other on `created_at`

Comment: Right you are...dumb question!